# Create multiple objects from user input

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create multiple objects from user input from a Jframe form. I've seen many posts on here on how to do this with the console, which all the answers end up being put in a loop; however none asking how to do this from a Jframe form.

[image: My form]

```
    private void CreateAccount() {
    String selected = UserSelectList.getSelectedValue();
    String setName = nameTboxSet.getText();
    String setType = UserTypeBoxSet.toString();            

    if ("user1" == selected) {user1.setName(setName); user1.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user2" == selected) {user2.setName(setName); user2.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user3" == selected) {user3.setName(setName); user3.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user4" == selected) {user4.setName(setName); user4.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user5" == selected) {user5.setName(setName); user5.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user6" == selected) {user6.setName(setName); user6.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user7" == selected) {user7.setName(setName); user7.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user8" == selected) {user8.setName(setName); user8.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user9" == selected) {user9.setName(setName); user9.setUserType(setType);}
    else if ("user10" == selected) {user10.setName(setName); user10.setUserType(setType);}
}
```

Above is what I have currently come up with, however honestly i dont think a list is necessary, i've tried many things to try and figure out how to get this work.

Comment: @MadProgrammer My emphasis is on netbeans.

Comment: Irrelevant, comparing `String` values in Java is a fundamental concept, one which you are doing wrong

Comment: I've used .equals () , wasn't sure if there's any difference in where and how i should use it as opposed to ==. I tried it again just then and get an error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: "however honestly i dont think a list is necessary". Can you explain why?

Comment: Additional gui fluff. I've been trying before i attempted to do it this way for it to check whether user1, user2, user3, etc has not been given any data and if it has not then thats the object the users input data will be added to. However with these methods it has seen that all of them are empty and has added the same user data to all of them and then cannot be attempted by the end user again. The reason is said that was that i believe that there must be a way to check if user1, user2 etc is empty automatically without the end user selecting what object they which to change the name/type of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have incorrectly determined which item has been selected. Assuming you used the java.awt.List component, this is how you would achieve what you have tried to do.

```
if (listName.getSelectedItem.equals(“user1”)){ ... }
```

For more information on this, please visit the Oracle documentation on the List component: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html

I have coded a quick example to show you it in action:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.List;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

    public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

        private JPanel contentPane;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public TestFrame() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

            List list = new List();
            list.add("user1", 0);
            list.add("user2", 1);
            list.add("user3", 2);
            list.add("user4", 3);
            list.add("user5", 4);
            list.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(list.getSelectedItem().equals("user1")){
                        System.out.println("User 1 has been selected!");
                    }else if(list.getSelectedItem().equals("user2")){
                        System.out.println("User 2 has been selected!");
                    }
                }           
            });

            contentPane.add(list);      
            setContentPane(contentPane);
        }

    }
```

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" referring to "getSelectedItem".

Comment: I added an example for you to easier understand.

Comment: Please select this as the correct answer if it is correct...

Comment: @Jurdun is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It's not far off, thanks